# How reliable is the concept of mainstream karma?

Tags: ethics, justice

This has nothing to do with any particular religions, rather the shared belief that nature will reward good people (people who act ethically) and will punish bad people (people who act unethically), it could also be correlated with phrases such as 'you reap what you sow'.

People often use this concept of justice to explain a good thing happening to a good person or a bad thing happening to a bad person, for example, if a politician is caught doing something that is shamed upon, then a few weeks or months later they get run over by a car, people will often use karma as an explanation; usually in an emotionally charged fashion. In fact, the concept is mostly cherry picked, as nothing similar is said when 'anti-karma' or 'injustice' occurs (evil being rewarded or good being punished). One look at this situation and the concept should seem questionable as it is a 50-50 chance, just like if we assigned two arbitrary events to happen, the arbitrariness renders the concept insignificant and unimportant. Relatively, there will be an equal share of good and bad things occurring in someone's life due to the fact that the mind, the brain, always adapts to its current environment; a multi-millionaire finding $1000 will be of little positive significance to them, whereas a homeless person finding $1000 may provoke an extreme euphoric high because of their previous misfortunes. At the end of both lives, there should be an equal amount of pleasure and pain experienced (this may look skewed, for example, a drug user, who seems miserable all their life, because they are, most of the time, compensating for the unequal instantaneous high they get from the drugs. And hence people who are ambitious high-achievers and sacrifice instant gratification for higher purposes tend to find enjoyment in their hard work as compensation, and live seemingly happier lives overall.)

And from a science perspective as well, the concept of karma seems even more arbitrary; the universe being so vast, how insignificant we and our actions are, why would there be a new law of physics/chemistry that states that an endorphin rush in one human caused by another human will bring about an equal endorphin rush in the human who caused the initial endorphin rush in the other human, and vice versa for pain with 'unethical' actions?

> New law of the universe -  "If an entity, a bipedal hairless primate on Planet Earth in particular, does an action that is regarded as shameful by the group/society they inhabit in, physical and chemical reactions will align themselves in such a manner that the primate's brain feels pain and/or the afflicted primates' brains feel pleasure."

It just seems ridiculous when rephrased logically in this way.

Comment: I've always (literally, as far back as I can remember) thought that this version of karma (not necessarily the Hindu concept so much) was contradictory. If I hurt someone, I seem to do wrong; if my hurting them is cosmic justice for something they did wrong, how was what I did wrong, though? Dante addresses this issue, perhaps with a reprehensible conclusion, when in the *Paradiso* he has Beatrice judge the destruction of Jerusalem to be a just punishment for the justified Crucifixion; maybe in a morally relative way this makes sense, but not so much on an absolutist conception.

Comment: I don't think that concept of natural retribution is quite universally shared. Another concept is that if you manage to pull the cover to yourself (metaphorically speaking) and do harm in the process but get away with it, you might reach a level of happiness that those who don't pull the cover to themselves will not enjoy (not that I agree).

Comment: The idea that karma means everyone will experience "justice" is strange if only because it seems to personify "to each his due". When I suffer bad karma, that need not result from anyone's wilful action besides my behaviour that created the bad karma. The agency when doing something immoral does not seem sufficient for 'justice': when I steal something and face legal justice, am I the agent of justice? I don't think so, even if I am caught red handed

Comment: "it [bad karma] is something neither gods nor men have put on me" (bodhidharma anthology). is that what you mean?